# Automatically order icons in Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, appearance

I was wondering, Is there a way to define automatically icon ordering, instead of make right click, order by, XXX. Every time I change a folder content I need to do that. Or change the view.

Comment: Are you saying that the Finder should arrange the icons according to your preference every time you open a Finder window or is the requirement to rearrange icons in a Finder Window as the folder content is changed?

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about the same way Windows apply the order to folders. No matter if you just open the folder or make any change to it, System's will automatically update the view. I just want all the icons from all the folder in my icon view to be ordered by name. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Choose View > Show View Options, or hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

In that window, you can select ordering for any folder individually, or hit Make Default to apply it for all windows.

Comment: Hello, and thanks. I tried to do that. But the option to make it default only works with the current folder.

Comment: Actually, making it default should apply the setting for all windows that don't have custom settings of their own.